# Error in Hive : For Exists/Not Exists operator SubQuery must be Correlated

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, exists

```
select * from students1;

students1.name  students1.age   students1.gpa
fred    35  1.28
barney  32  2.32
shyam   32  2.32

select * from students2;
students1.name  students1.age
fred    35
barney  32
```

When I am running this query

```
select 
name,age from students1
where not exists
(select name,age from students2);
```

I am getting this bellow error

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException line 39:22
>   Invalid SubQuery expression 'age' in definition of SubQuery sq_1 [
>   exists (select name,age from students2) ] used as sq_1 at Line 3:10:
>   For Exists/Not Exists operator SubQuery must be Correlated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is clear. The subquery should be correlated when using `exists`/`not exists`.

```
select name,age 
from students1 s1
where not exists (select 1
                  from students2 s2
                  where s1.name=s2.name and s1.age=s2.age
                 )
```

Comment: what does this 1 means

Comment: Is there no simple way to achieve this, as I have to write queries to compare data between source and target table

Comment: If I have 100 columns then will I have to write s1.x=s2.x and s1.a=s2.b .... like wise for 100 columns

Comment: @Kumar 1 is just an arbitrary value because the only thing that we need is that the subquery returns a value, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to achieve a `MINUS` output of a query. It is **unfortunately not available** in Hive.

You can read through the limitations of HQL and SQL here.  [HQL  vs SQL](https://www.quora.com/Apache-Hive/What-are-the-biggest-feature-gaps-between-HiveQL-and-SQL)

For usage of not exists, the manual has good example.
[subqueries in hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries)

Answer (score 0):

`MINUS` is now available in Hive. You can achieve this as the following:

```
select name,age from students1
MINUS
select name,age from students2;
```